# .wsp Package deployed on the server

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-enterprise

i have developed a .wsp package and i got the access to the server(application server) to deploy it.. when i deployed the package and i try to access the site i was getting the error Service Unavailable(HTTP ERROR 503) .. when talk with admin earlier today he said that all application pools were stopped and he started them again, so when i accessed the site it was working again... now i again deployed it the same thing happen, (admin has left for the day)..since i have access to the server..i think the same thing must have happen ..any suggestion as to where can i go and find these application pools and start them again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application pools are on the servers themselves. Since you are deploying WSP files I assume you are already remoting into the server. You have to open up IIS manager which will allow you to start the application pools.

IIS7 - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732742%28WS.10%29.aspx

You may also want to view the sites and make sure that all SharePoint related sites are started as well. These will also be in IIS manager.

Comment: I'd also inspect the IIS and ULS logs on the servers, as something is stopping the application pools from restarting when the WSP is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause should be of interest to you too. I suggest that you read a post by Waldek on [Optimizing the deployment process](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/optimizing-deploying-sharepoint-packages-minimize-impact-farm-availability/)